# Combining .ARFF Files - Weka

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

So I have 4 .ARFF files that I need to combine into one in order to train a decision tree using ID3. Is there a built in method in order to combine these files? I was unable to figure it out from the documentation.

Thanks

edit: Note that all the files have the same type of data and headers.

Comment: There is not a built in method that I am aware of.  However, depending on the size of each of these file, you could open them with a text editor and simply copy the contents from one file and paste it under the header of another.

Comment: You could run weka from command line:  java weka.core.Instances append filename1 filename2 > output-file       , than add filename3 to output-file and so on...